# helm release monitor tool

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Is there any tool can monitor helm release ? 
You may come up with this one https://github.com/ContainerSolutions/helm-monitor, but i don't want automatic rollback by plugin. This is intrusive to our ci/cd deployment.

what i need. 
1. i can integrate with grafana to see a history of the release and also its status in history 
2. I can set up alerts when some release is stuck in pending or failed then i can notify related teams